# How to filter based on has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have 3 models

Project

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end
```

Tagging

```
class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Tag

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :projects, through: :taggings
end
```

In short Projects have many Tags thorough Taggings.

I want to find out projects which have **all given tags**. My input is an array of `tag` ids(for example [1,3,5]). I tried with
`Project.joins(:tags).where(tags: {id: [1 ,3, 5]})`
but it finds projects who have either one of the tags with id from `[1,3,5]`. I am looking for projects which have all of the input tags. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a "contains" query:

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM projects p
         INNER JOIN taggings t ON p.id = t.project_id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING array_agg(t.tag_id ORDER BY t.tag_id) @> ARRAY [1, 3, 5];
```

This will return all the projects that have all given tags but not limited to them. i.e. if a project has tags `1, 3, 5, 7`, it will be returned to. But not a project that

A couple of conditions:

1. `ARRAY [1, 3, 5]` must be sorted
2. `p.id` (which is really `projects.id`) must: a) be the primary key or b) have a uniqueness constraint attached to it.

The advantage of doing it this way is that the query is flexible — you can change the operation to quickly change meaning. Say, instead of "return a project will all of these tags", you could now write "return a project with *only* these tags".

Consider this data set:

```
projects:

id  name
1   guttenberg
2   x
3   aristotle


tags:

id  name
1   books
2   teams
3   management
4   library
5   movie

taggings:

id  project_id  tag_id
1   1   1
2   1   3
3   1   5
4   2   1
5   2   3
6   3   4
7   3   5
```

If you were to query for `1, 3`, you should get projects 1 and 2.

A SQL fiddle to play with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/345dd0/9/1

Equivalent ActiveRecord:

```rb
tag_ids = [1, 5, 3].sort # condition 1
projects = 
  Project.joins(:taggings) # don't need tags
    .group(:id)
    .having("array_agg(taggings.tag_id ORDER BY taggings.tag_id) @> ARRAY[?]", tag_ids)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
tags = [1, 3, 5]
projects = Project.joins(:tags)
                  .where(tags: {id: tags})
                  .group(:id)
                  .having('COUNT(tags) = ?', tags.size)
```

This will return Projects that have all three tags.

Comment: I'm wrong here, the query doesn't fetch the right projects.

Comment: I have used the array contains approach in my code. Why do you think this doesn't work? It gave accurate results for me on a few tests.

Comment: The array approach works, my suggestion doesn't. For a project with 4 tags (ids: 1, 3, 5 and 7), filtering for tags 1, 3, 5 and count = 3, that project will be found, all conditions will match. It's doing the wrong thing here, that's a false positive.